# $(".column").sortable is not a function

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am getting the said error

```
$(".column").sortable is not a function
```

I m trying to create sortable/movable divs in my code. 
Issue is that if I m using a new project then the code is working fine, but when I try to run it in my project it gives me the said error.. 
Any idea??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have forgot to add your jquery-ui script library to the page. Add the following within the head section to see if it works.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Well I have added these libraries to my project and given their reference aswel in my project

Comment: Is it in that particular order? Can you show your $(".column").sortable code